# how do I create a custom button on a standard object which is linked to a visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I want to place a custom button on the Opportunity detail page. this button if clicked will pop all the record data into a excel sheet.

how do i approach this, i know how to export with content type and linking it to a button with pagereference, but i have tried all that in VF pages with custom controller only.

for opportunity, how do i create a button and place it and then link it to a vf page that exports all the data to excel sheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link you can follow:

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/export-excel-using-visualforce-page/

This example is for Account standard object. You just create the similar page for Opportunity and then create a button by going to:

1. Go to **Setup --> Opportunities --> Buttons, Links and actions**.
2. Click New Button or Link.
3. Follow the below Screenshot, and don't forget to get the button on layout.

[image]

Comment: Thanks,
I was told to do this, i was thinking of doing with VF.
1.Create a VF with apex detail to display all opportunity details 
2.Create another VF which will export all data to excel,with contenttype help.
3.Create a controller class which will pagereference the second VF page when the button is clicked on.

This was my first approach but the issue with this was that I cant use both standard and custom controller on top and i cant do both right.
Just think if you had to do this with all VF,is my above thinking steps right although just missing some steps to include both controllers?

Comment: why can't you use both? You can definitely use standardController with extension(custom controller class). https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_Controllers_and_Extensions

Comment: if the above answer has helped you to get an idea of your solution, then select it as answer, it will help other members in future.

Answer (score 0):

Create a VF page with a controller that start the export process.

Then in the opportunity "buttons, links and actions" section create a "new button" for "Detail Page". Select your preferred opening behaviour.

Select source = "URL"

In the formula enter: `{!URLFOR('/apex/YOUR_VF_PAGE_NAME?id=' + Opportunity.Id)}`

Of course replace with the proper VF page name

Comment: When i select visualforce page in the content source multipicklist , there is no formula box to enter, it is only available for the URL option in the content source.
thanks

Comment: Right, select URL, forgot that step and added it.